# problem with generate scaffold_controller(bug?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to generate my CRUD scripts with scaffold_controller 
I am using:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.10) 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 >
```

My model is quite simple: 
class Orgjed < ActiveRecord::Base 
end 
And in my schema this is how it writes:

```
  create_table "orgjeds", :force => true do |t| 
    t.string   "naziv" 
    t.datetime "created_at" 
    t.datetime "updated_at" 
  end
```

and I am trying to create controller and all scripts with 
rails generate scaffold_controller Orgjed 
After that, script seems to do everything ok:

```
... 
      create    app/views/orgjeds/index.html.erb 
      create    app/views/orgjeds/edit.html.erb 
...
```

After I start a server and try to go to correct path this is what I got back in my browser:

```
NoMethodError in Orgjeds#index 
Showing xxx/ev_rada/app/views/orgjeds/index.html.erb where line #12 
raised: 
undefined method `orgjed_path' for #<#<Class:0x9fbe1dc>:0x9fb0cf8> 
Extracted source (around line #12): 
9: 
10: <% @orgjeds.each do |orgjed| %> 
11:   <tr> 
12:     <td><%= link_to 'Show', orgjed %></td> 
13:     <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_orgjed_path(orgjed) %></td> 
14:     <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', orgjed, :confirm => 'Are you 
sure?', :method => :delete %></td> 
15:   </tr>
```

also, I looked into _form.html.erb 
and there are no fields like naziv... 
Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong? 
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to use the simple `rails g scaffold Model attributes`?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have missed to configure the routes. Add the following line in routes.rb:

```
resources :orgjeds
```

Comment: hm...now I cant even load server, and got this error => Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.10 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/dorijan/ruby/ev_rada/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `map' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x864181c> (NameError), also I got in my routes match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'

Comment: Have updated my post. If that doesn't work post us your routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by installing and using Niftygenerators

http://compautomatization.blogspot.com/2011/08/ruby-on-rails-3-scaffoldcontroller-not.html